# php xml attribute value replace

Tags: php

Say i have an xml file of this nature
 
  
   
    some data

I wan to replace attributes of each later using one function in php:
example say: 
replaceAttribute("collections","somecollection,"newcollection");

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_setattribute1 . Hope it helps